# As a method parameter in Java, what does the question mark allow you to do in Class<?>

Tags: java, spring, gwt

With the code segment below what does the question mark allow you to do, since it is in angle brackets by a class type? Does it allow for any class type to be passed in as a parameter?

Also, what does method 1 return? Does it return an object that can be cast to an `ObjectService` type?

### method 1

```
public Object getInstance(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (org.service.ObjectService.class.equals(clazz))
        return getObjectService();
    return null;
}
```

### method 2

```
public ObjectService getObjectService() {
    ObjectService service;

    service = (ObjectService) context.getBean("ObjectService");

    return service;
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It tells the compiler to accept any type of Class as a parameter.
Basically, this way you choose to turn off compiler's type check.
Alternatively, you can omit `<?>` altogether with a compiler warning or do as Luiggi suggested and specify `Class<Object>`, which is not always the same though.

If your generic class is defined with restrictions, `<Object>` would not be an acceptable parameter.

For instance, if you have the following class somewhere:

```
public class TheClass<T extends Component> {
}
```

You can't do `TheClass<Object>`. You can do `TheClass<Component>` or `TheClass<?>`, which are essentially the same for TheClass case.

---

UPDATE TO ANSWER UPDATED QUESTION

getInstance() in your case will defer to getObjectService(), which can only return ObjectService. You're guaranteed to receive one of the following:

- ObjectService instance.
- null.
- ClassCastException from method getObjectService(), where casting is performed.

Comment: Thank you, ATrubka! I don't yet understand what the restrictions would possibly be. Also, What do you mean when you say "You can't do TheClass."

Comment: I guess formatting got screwed up in my answer. I should've marked it with code quotes. I fixed it and I hope it's clear now. Basically, you can only parametrize TheClass with something that extends Component or is Component itself.